# How do I stop getting this append error in python?

Tags: python-3.x

We have a class, `Message`, which models an e-mail message. A message has a recipient, a sender, and a message text. The class supports the following methods:

- a constructor, which accepts the sender and recipient as arguments
- `append` that takes one string argument and appends it to the message body as a new line
- `__str__` that makes the message into one long string like this: "From: Harry Morgan\nTo: Rudolf Reindeer\n\nCome to the North Pole."

The error message I keep getting is at the bottom, how do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self,sender,recipient,message=[]):
        self.sender = sender
        self.recipient = recipient 
        self.message = message

    def append(self,message): 
        self.message=self.message.append(message)

    def __str__(self): 
        print("\nFROM: "+sender+"\n"+"TO: "+recipient+"\n\n"+self.message)
def main():
    message = []
    sender = input('Who is sending the message: ')
    recipient = input('Who would you like to send the message to: ')
    body = input('Enter body (blank line to quit): ')
    while body != '':
        message.append(body)
        body = input('Enter body (blank line to quit): ')
        if body == '':
            break
    print()
    print('FROM:', sender)
    print('TO:', recipient)
    print()
    print(*message,sep='\n') 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  

An error occurred when appending a line to the message!
```

Comment: Is there more to the code?  Your code worked fine for me.  Plus that doesn't look like a standard Python error message.

Comment: My class uses Zybooks as our form of submission and that was the error I got. I received credit for the output itself, but it keeps telling me there was an error somewhere. Sorry if this is confusing, this is my first time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. You never instantiated your `Message` class. What I mean, is that you never wrote anything such as `message = Message()`. As such, no errors occur.
   I recommend something like the following:

   ```
   def main():
       sender = input('Who is sending the message: ')
       recipient = input('Who would you like to send the message to: ')

       message = Message(sender, recipient)

       body = input('Enter body (blank line to quit): ')
       while body != '':
           message.append(body)
           body = input('Enter body (blank line to quit): ')
           if body == '':
               break

       print(str(message))
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
2. Inside of `__str__` you are missing `self.` before `sender` and before `recipient`

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       print("\nFROM: "+ self.sender+"\n"+"TO: "+self.recipient+"\n\n"+self.message)
   ```
3. Currently, your `__str__` method returns `None` and prints the string. What if you want the actual string? `stryng = str(message)` won't work, because `stryng` will be `None`

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return "\nFROM: "+ self.sender+"\n"+"TO: "+self.recipient+"\n\n"+self.message
   ```
4. Using `+` on strings, such as `"hello world" == "hello" + ' ' +" world"` is very inefficient. Almost never do it. Use a string streams instead:

   ```
   import io

   def __str__(self):
       with io.StringIO as ss:
           print(
               "\nFROM: ", self.sender,
               "\nTO: ", self.recipient,
               "\n\n", self.message,
               file = ss
           )
           stryng = ss.getvalue()
       return stryng
   ```
5. `append` modifies "***in-place***". It does not return a modified copy.

   ```
   def append(self,message):
       self.message=self.message.append(message)
   ```

   If you don't write a `return` statement, what gets returned? `None`

   ```
   def append(self,message):
       self.message=self.message.append(message)
       return None
   ```

   What is on the right-hand-side of the `=` operator?

   ```
   def append(self,message):
       self.message = None
       return None
   ```

Comment: RE 2/3: Adding `self.message` will fail since it's a list of strings, not a string itself. RE 4: I don't think I've ever seen a `StringIO` used that way. A much simpler, and perhaps more Pythonic solution is to use `str.format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def append(self,message): 
    self.message=self.message.append(message)
```

This will end up setting self.message to None. As you are setting it to the return value of append function which is None. 
You should use this instead.

```
def append(self,message): 
    self.message.append(message)
```